# How to loop the subtraction of the value in the first row to values in the same column

Tags: r, loops, tidyr

I am looking for a function/loop that picks out first the first cell of subvalues to subtract the subvalue in the second cell, then on the 2nd loop picking out the 2nd cell, etc. Then loop to do so for every column

For example:
[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rdZ5.png)

G1 - G2, G1 - G3, G1- G4 etc. Then G2 - G3, G2 - G4 etc.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.) Also post the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to subtract complete 1st row with 2nd row, 1st with 3rd and so on till last row and then 2nd row with 3rd, 2nd with 4th and so on till last row and like this till the last row?

I think `combn` can help you achieve this :

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = 4:8)
mat <- combn(seq(nrow(df)), 2)
result <- df[mat[1, ], ] - df[mat[2, ], ]
```

where `mat` returns all row combinations :

```
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3*5, 25, 5), ncol = 3)) # 5 rows for demo
colnames(data) = c("A","B","C")
rownames(data) = paste("G",seq(1,nrow(data)), sep = "")
```

The generated data looks like this:

| -- | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 14.83125 | 21.33644 | 21.99278 |
| G2 | 33.88000 | 28.63547 | 29.96025 |
| G3 | 30.60549 | 22.31251 | 16.20981 |
| G4 | 29.74367 | 30.92053 | 20.39461 |
| G5 | 17.99330 | 31.33550 | 26.07054 |

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(data)-1)){
    print(apply(data[(i+1):nrow(data),], 1, function(x) data[i,] - x ))
}
```

This prints the following output:

```
$G2
           A         B         C
G1 -19.04875 -7.299035 -7.967464

$G3
           A         B         C
G1 -15.77425 -0.9760759 5.782972

$G4
           A         B         C
G1 -14.91243 -9.584088 1.598178

$G5
           A         B         C
G1 -3.162052 -9.999061 -4.077752

$G3
           A         B         C
G2  3.274505  6.322959  13.75044

$G4
           A         B         C
G2  4.136325 -2.285053  9.565641

$G5
           A         B         C
G2   15.8867 -2.700026  3.889712

$G4
           A         B         C
G3 0.8618196 -8.608012 -4.184794

$G5
          A          B         C
G3 12.61219  -9.022985 -9.860724

$G5
          A          B         C
G4 11.75037  -0.414973  -5.67593
```